# Python: catching particular exception

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have such code (Python 2.5, GAE dev server):

```
try:
    yt_service.UpgradeToSessionToken() // this line produces TokenUpgradeFailed
except gdata.service.TokenUpgradeFailed:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(auth_sub_url()) # this line will never be executed (why?)
except Exception, exc:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(auth_sub_url()) # instead this line is executed (why?)
```

So I set breakpoint at last line and under debugger I see:

```
"exc"   TokenUpgradeFailed: {'status': 403, 'body': 'html stripped', 'reason': 'Non 200 response on upgrade'}   
"type(exc)" type: <class 'gdata.service.TokenUpgradeFailed'>
"exc is gdata.service.TokenUpgradeFailed"   bool: False 
"exc.__class__" type: <class 'gdata.service.TokenUpgradeFailed'>
"isinstance(exc, gdata.service.TokenUpgradeFailed)" bool: False 
"exc.__class__.__name__"    str: TokenUpgradeFailed
```

What I missed in python exception handling? Why isinstance(exc, gdata.service.TokenUpgradeFailed) is False?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error can occur if your relative/absolute `import` statements do not match everywhere. If there is a mismatch, the target module can be loaded more than once and in slightly different contexts. Usually this isn't a problem but it does prevent classes from the differently loaded modules from comparing as equal (hence the exception catching problem).

There may be other causes for the error but I suggest looking through your code and ensuring that everything importing the `gdata.service` module explicitly mentions the `gdata` package. Even within the `gdata` package itself, each module using the `service` module should import it from the package explicitly via `from gdata import service` rather than by way of the relative import: `import service`.